# in the nature of

Tags: difference

I need help in understanding the context of "in the nature of" in these sentences

- > electronic control devices for automobiles in the nature of electronic controls for throttle angle
- > electronic control devices for automobiles in the nature of electronic controls for vehicle speed

Answer (score 1):

*In the nature of* means *characteristic of* or *typical of*.

The examples you give are all types of electronic control for various motoring functions. But a type of electronic control cannot idiomatically be described as being *in the nature of* electronic controls. It is merely an example or variety of electronic control.

For typical uses of *in the nature of*, see:

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nature-of-things

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_the_nature_of

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-the-nature-of-things